# Is there literature available on iterated function systems of the form $f^n = (g f^{n - 1}, g f^{n - 2}, \ldots)$?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

This question is motivated by [another question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052783/mandelbrot-and-julia-set).

From a function $g:X^k\to X$ it is possible to define an iterated function system on $X^k$ with the function $f:X^k\to X^k$ defined by

$$f(x) = (g(x), x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k - 1}).$$

Iterates of $f$ are given by

$$f^n = f f^{n - 1} = (g f^{n - 1}, f^{n - 1}_1, \ldots, f^{n - 1}_{k - 1})$$

and when $n > k$ an exercise in tedious definition chasing yields

$$f^n = (g f^{n - 1}, g f^{n - 2}, \ldots, g f^{n - k}).$$

The linked question describes such a system where, $X = B(z, r)$, an open ball in $\mathbb{C}$, $k = 2$, and $g(x) = (\alpha + x_1)/(1 + x_2)$.

My question is:

> Is there literature available describing these types of iterated function systems?

I wonder if these systems have a name.  I have not had much luck trying to describe them to google.

In the special case where $k = 1$ these are just "normal" iterated function systems and there is a plethora of literature describing techniques for analyzing their dynamics; however it is not clear to me which tools I can justifiably bring to bear when the next point in the iteration depends on the current point *and* several previous points.

Comment: Probably not particularly helpful, but if your map g is linear then I think your systems have been studied by Akiyama and others under the name 'shift radix systems'. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0386v1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(More an answomment)*. I'd say your iteration on $X^k$ is what one gets  by a standard reduction  writing a $k$-order recurrence on $X$,
$$x_{n}=g(x_{n-1},x_{n-2},\dots,x_{n-k}),\qquad x_i\in X$$
in form of a first-order recurrence on $X^k$, 
$$y^{n+1}=f(y^n),\qquad y^n=(y^n_1,\dots,y^n_k)\in X^k$$
putting $y^n_i:=x_{n-i}$. (By the analog reduction, one writes a $k$-order scalar ODE as a first order system on $\mathbb{R}^k$). Since $X$ in your setting seems to be quite a general object, your iteration  $y\mapsto f(y)$ is actually a more special rather than more general  iteration, and the question is, what implications has the special form of $f$ on the dynamics. To start with, for instance, if $g$ is a linear form on $X:=\mathbb{C}$, the corresponding matrix  $f$ has all eigenvalues of geometric multiplicity $1$. I guess you may like to refer to the theory of higher order recurrences to check if some result may be of interest for you when traslated in your setting.

Comment: Thanks, Pietro.  I think the term "k-order recurrence" is helpful.  I hadn't thought of that phrasing when I searched for references earlier.  I cooked up all that extra notation with $f:X^k\to X^k$ only because I was worried that I wouldn't be able to precisely describe the notion of carrying along the $k$ previous points in an IFS, but ultimately the extra notation may not be helpful.  Everything that's going on is described perfectly well in your definition of $x_n$.